# SAPUI5 Link sending two parameters

Tags: hyperlink, href, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 Link on my page and I want to use it to call another php file with two parameters. As far as I can see, I am formatting the XML properly but when I try to include the second parameter in the 'href' property, I get an error that the XML is not formatted properly.

Here is the XML for the link - I have modified the href to remove sensitive server information:

```
<Link id="pdfLink" xmlns="sap.m" text="PDF" href="https://../scripts/pdf/index.php?yr={/yr}&qtr={/qtr}" target="_blank"></Link>
```

When the URL is triggered, it should look similar to this in the browser:

```
https://../scripts/pdf/index.php?yr=2015&qtr=1
```

This will launch the index.php file with the parameters, if entered manually. If I remove the '&qtr={/qtr}' (or even just the &), then I don't get an error that the XML is invalid, but of course then the 'qtr' parameter is not sent.

I also tried switching the & with a ; which did not cause the invalid XML error, but the second parameter is not read in the php as being there. How can I send both parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Well after I posted my question, I thought of something....the & wasn't being interpreted as a &, so I changed the Link to be:

```
 <Link id="pdfLink" xmlns="sap.m" text="Create PDF" href="https://.../scripts/pdf/index.php?yr={/yr}&amp;qtr={/qtr}" target="_blank"></Link>
```

(I changed the & to be &) This change worked!